# Second Item selected in listview doesn't show the correct value

Tags: vb.net

[See pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldqXU.jpg) When I add all price columns it works perfectly fine. But, when I just select that second item it just show the value of the first row but then when I select the first item it shows its correct value.Anyway, here's my code:

```
Private Sub btnttotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnttotal.Click

        Dim totalPrice As Integer = 0
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While (i < ListView1.SelectedItems.Count)
            totalPrice = (totalPrice + Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(2).Text))
            i = (i + 1)
            txttotal.Text = totalPrice
        Loop


    End Sub
```

Comment: `When I add all columns` I suspect you means *rows*.  But the code is adding rows 0 thru `ListView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1` which, with just 2 rows, is that first row.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Private Sub btnttotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnttotal.Click

    Dim totalPrice As Integer = 0
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do While (i < ListView1.SelectedItems.Count)
        totalPrice = (totalPrice + Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.SelectedItems(i).SubItems(2).Text))
        i = (i + 1)
        txttotal.Text = totalPrice
    Loop

End Sub
```

If you look at the above solution, to calculate the total, only the selected values should be take into consideration. But you were calculating for all the rows of the listbox by this line `totalPrice = (totalPrice + Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(2).Text))`. So when you select second row, your `DO WHILE` loops only one time as the selected row is one, and your calculation was picking values from start and `100` is the first value and it was stopping with that. I hope you understand the mistake.

If you want to do the calculation efficiently and simply, i would suggest this :

```
Dim totalPrice As Integer = 0
For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems.Cast(Of ListViewItem)()
    totalPrice += Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems(2).Text)
Next

txttotal.Text = totalPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the indexes of the selected items with those of all items. `ListView1.SelectedItems` and `ListView1.Items` are two different collections.

If would be easier to just get the sum like this

```
Dim totalPrice As Integer = ListView1.SelectedItems _
    .Cast(Of ListViewItem)() _
    .Sum(Function(item) Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems(2).Text))
```

This enumerates the collection `SelectedItems` directly without using any indexes.

To avoi using indexes you can also do it with a for each loop

```
Dim totalPrice As Integer = 0
For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems.Cast(Of ListViewItem)()
    totalPrice += Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems(2).Text)
Next
```

Instead of using the click event of a button, you could also upate the total price textbox by using `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `ListView`. That ay it would update automatically.

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim totalPrice As Integer = 0
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems.Cast(Of ListViewItem)()
        totalPrice += Convert.ToInt32(item.SubItems(2).Text)
    Next
    txttotal.Text = CType(totalPrice, String)
End Sub
```